# Why does a neutral atom have no external electric field?

Tags: electric-fields, atomic-physics, orbitals, quantum-chemistry, multipole-expansion

I've been trying to find an answer to this for some time now. In advance, I imagine the orbital model, nevertheless I cannot imagine that if I am for example closer to a side of the atom, the dipole of the electron which is turned to me is extinguished by all other dipoles (because the electron is so to speak almost everywhere at the same time [it is a quantum field, or electron cloud]) further away. I thought first the Gauss law would be an explanation for it but unfortunately not.

Comment: Your question needs clarification and supporting information. The description of your question is confusing and so is the title. Do you mean why for example a noble gas atom like for example He-4 has no charge or a magnetic dipole moment?

Comment: @Markoul11 sorry, but my comment is too long for Stackexchange: https://pastebin.com/u5tmhCnh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does a neutral atom have no external electric field?

Why do you think this is true?  How do you think the bonding of atoms into solids happen?

Take the van [der waals forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force)

> Van der Waals forces include attraction and repulsions between atoms, molecules, and surfaces, as well as other intermolecular forces. They differ from covalent and ionic bonding in that they are caused by correlations in the fluctuating polarizations of nearby particles (a consequence of quantum dynamics).

....

> 2. Attractive or repulsive electrostatic interactions between permanent charges (in the case of molecular ions), dipoles (in the case of molecules without inversion centre), quadrupoles (all molecules with symmetry lower than cubic), and in general between permanent multipoles. The electrostatic interaction is sometimes called the Keesom interaction or Keesom force after Willem Hendrik Keesom.

> 3. Induction (also known as polarization), which is the attractive interaction between a permanent multipole on one molecule with an induced multipole on another. This interaction is sometimes called Debye force after Peter J.W. Debye.

Qualitatively, in terms of orbitals, there are positive and negative electric fields depending on the shape of the orbitals , that allow for attraction between atoms and molecules:

[image: orbital]

> [Suitably aligned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital)  atomic orbitals overlap to form phi molecular orbital (a phi bond)

Comment: Ok, but maybe if you have a single atom in vacuum with L=S=J=0 you really have no field.. I think this is the real question.

Comment: @Quillo  if there is spherical symmetry in the orbitals , after some distance the fields are balanced. But it depends on the type of atom or molecule, if it is like the image, there will be stray fields even for large distances, of positive spilling out from the nucleus and negative from the electrons.