# Can Wavelength also be used as Circumference?

Tags: angular-momentum, electrons, atoms, wavelength, angular-velocity

Could Lights wavelength be the result of the electron orbits and its distance? Could this be why wavelength and orbit circumference measurements are the same?

This would imply that wavelength radius would double as orbit distance....

Speed of Light / Wavelength = Frequency

Speed of Light / Frequency = Wavelength

Frequency x Pi x 2 = Angular Velocity

Wavelength x 0.31831 = Diameter / 2 = Radius

Wavelength / Pi = Diameter / 2 = Radius

Speed of Light / Radius = Angular Velocity

Radius x Angular Velocity = Speed of Light

these formulas seem to work with wavelength and circumference as the same measurements....So why is wavelength not also used as electron orbit circumference?

Comment: because we have discovered electrons do not move in orbits, but in orbitals , see this answer of mine https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/684780/ . Modeling atoms needs quantum mechanics and is much more complicated than the simple Bohr model with  the orbits you assume. also this question and answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20003/

Comment: Although eveni n the qm model there is a relation between the energy of transitions between orbitals and wavelength. So you are  not onto nothing even if the models you are using are over simplified.